# Change default terminal directory in WebStorm

Tags: terminal, editor, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 2016.2 as my IDE at the moment and I like the built in terminal. The one thing that would make it better for me would be the ability to specify a default project terminal directory. The reason is, my project directory looks like

```
application/
build/
deploy/
```

Most of the time I'm working in the `application` directory and that's where my `package.json` is to run all my `npm` commands. It's a pain having to move directory every time I start the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's fixed now so you can do it like this :**

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It's opening in a totally different directory than what's specified there. But I think those settings are ignored, anyway, as I've also specified I want to use `pwsh.exe` (PS 7), yet WebStorm launches PowerShell 5.1.

Answer (score 2):

Currently it's not possible.

Watch (star/vote/comment) these tickets (mainly first one) to get notified on progress:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125383
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118543

---

Right now the best I can offer is to grab & drag desired folder and drop it at already opened terminal (at tabs space) -- it will open new tab with that folder as current path.

Answer (score 0):

This has now been fixed in the latest WebStorm build.

Comment: well how do you do it then?

Comment: @tatsu only seeing this now. It says how to do it at the top of this post. There is a screenshot.

Comment: I know :) look at who posted it!